# Failed opening '../tweets.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:')

Tags: php

I am trying to include a script using the following code.

```
<div class="main_content">
    <?php include ('tweets.php')  ?>
</div>
```

But it keeps throwing up the following error.

> Warning: include(tweets.php): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in - on line 52 Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   'tweets.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:') in - on line 52

I have checked and double checked and the file definitely exists and is in the same directory as the file that this is in.

I really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: try `echo __DIR__;` and make sure that your directory matches where your file actually resides.

Comment: @ehime thank you for your comment, this is simply showing as '/'

Comment: Try this to see if in the / directory. `foreach (glob("*.php") as $f) echo "$f<br />";`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The path is relative to the file where the request was initiated. 
So, even if it's in the same folder as the file it's including, if that file was included from a file in a different folder, you will have to use an absolute path or a path relative to the original file.

Comment: and what if I set it in `include_path=` variable in php.ini ?

Answer (score 5):

Try using `include('./tweets.php');`. If that does not resolve your issue, it's most likely file permissions. Give everyone full permissions for tweets.php and see if that works.

Comment: permissions! pay attention to it

Answer (score 4):

As @Josh says, the path is relative to the file that received the request, so you can exploit the PHP `__DIR__` [magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php):

```
include(__DIR__ . '/tweets.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. same message but i fix it...cleaning all the blank spaces before and after php symbols `<?php` and `?>`
2. make sure `{` and `}` are not missing and where they need to be
3. make sure this syntax is correctly where it need to be `{` and `<?php } ?>`
   No need for an extra path... Thank You very much

> Warning: include(tweets.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in - on line 52 Warning: include(): Failed opening 'tweets.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:') in - on line 52

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Neither does your other answer. What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

1.)if you have 2 different variables is a different scenario like same name one variable with upper case and one variable with lower case...different solution you are right thank you very much

2.)but if someone could change the variables to be complete different variables names they  may not have that problem....not always the case

Answer (score -2):

That's because your file name not found due to "case sensitive". Example "./Core/admin.php" and "./core/admin.php" are diffrent.