# Unable to include file from subfolder - PHP

Tags: php, include

This is line to include file from subfolder but I get errors

```
include('../classes/user.php');
```

Error:

> PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '../classes/phpmailer/mail.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/site/public_html/sm/assets/includes/config.php

I also tried

```
include(__DIR__ .'/classes/user.php');
```

but same error.
Any idea how it can be solved?
Thanks.

Comment: At a guess, I'd say the file doesn't exist or you don't have permissions to read it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed opening '../tweets.php' for inclusion (include\_path='.:')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861828/failed-opening-tweets-php-for-inclusion-include-path)

Comment: Your error is not coming from the file you're including its coming from another file that's also being included see path on error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your code suggests the file you want to include is in the folder:

```
/home/site/public_html/sm/assets/classes/user.php
```

If that is not the case, for example it is in:

```
/home/site/public_html/classes/user.php
```

you need to add something like this:

```
include '../../../classes/user.php';
```

--edit:

I now also see the error is actually about "../classes/phpmailer/mail.php"
It seems that that mail.php is not in that place... You probably need to verify that first. The error comes from config.php. So check out the include for mail.php and check the path